# In Sitecore how to set the time limit for deletion of logs?

Tags: sitecore

If I want the error logs to be deleted after 2 months , how can I achieve it ? do I need to code or it can be done directly from Sitecore?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's a good post on how to do this:

http://kirkegaard-at.blogspot.co.uk/2014/09/cleanupagent-and-log-files.html

You can adjust the settings on the clean up agent

Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent

Also you could archive the files after a certain amount of time rather than deleting them. John west has a great article here on how to implement archiving of log files.

https://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2013/01/cleanup-log-clutter-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Sitecore logs get deleted by CleanUp agent configured in Sitecore.config. Existing cleanup agent has an issue though. Its regex dont delete the log files with name like log.txt.1 (these files get created when a log reaches the size limit). The regex needs to be updated from

```
*log.*.txt
```

to

```
*log.*.txt*
```

You can create a patch that deletes logs more frequently like this -

```
<configuration xmlns:patch="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/" xmlns:set="http://www.sitecore.net/xmlconfig/set/">
<sitecore>        
    <scheduling>
        <agent type="Sitecore.Tasks.CleanupAgent">          
            <files>
                <remove folder="$(dataFolder)/logs" set:pattern="*log.*.txt*" />
            </files>
        </agent>
    </scheduling>
</sitecore>
```

Comment: Looks like this issue is worse on their out of the box PaaS options as well - by default logs are stored in a sub-folder of the logs folder, so also needs `recursive="true"` added.

Comment: I want to have multiple pattern for same folder, is it possible?